# How do I stop Gthumb from opening when I plug in my camera?

Tags: linux-mint, autoplay

I'm using Linux Mint 13.  Whenever I plug my camera into the USB port, Gthumb opens *and* a directory window opens.  I can't find config files, autoplay options or an option in the preferences of Gthumb to change this.

How can I stop Gthumb opening when I plug in my camera?

O_O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find `Removable media` in the `System Settings` menu, check `Never prompt or start programs on media insertion` or Install `dconf Editor` using `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`.Then launch `dconf Editor`,navigate to org/gnome/desktop/media-handling and uncheck `automount`, you can even try https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/7/removable-drive-menu/ A neat little extension that adds a removable drives icon to the top panel when you insert one, from there you can then choose to open a nautilus window or eject.

Answer (score 4):

In Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon the `Removable Media` settings are under `System Settings > Preferred Applications`.